# make link to column excluding certain value(s) in excel

Tags: arrays, excel, sorting

Ok,. Here, I have a column of values, which are ascending order numbers. At certain points, sequence is broken and 0 's are replacing the values. Its like , 1,2,3,0,0,6,0,8,... in continuous cells of a column. Now, I want another column to be linked to this one, but instead of the zeros, the next non zero number appearing on the sequence should be shown. ie. a link to array which exclude a certain value and skips its place. I want it to be in realtime, either using formulas or using macros. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I got it now (hopefully)... what you are looking for is doable with a simple "SMALL"-function like:

```
D2: =IFERROR(SMALL(A:A,COUNTIF(A:A,0)+ROW()-1),"")
E2: =IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(D2,A:A,0)),"")
```

The formulas then simply can be copied down. The `-1` is the offset for not starting in row 1 (starting at row 25 would need `-24`). The `COUNTIF` is simply for skipping out the 0's.

Should be pretty much self explaining, but if you still have any questions, just ask :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Starting with a blank or zero in C1, and assuming the list of numbers starts in A2 and numbers aren't repeated, you could look for the next number which  is greater than the number above starting in C2:-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$10,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A$2:A$10>C1,0),0)),"")
```

Is this what you meant?

[image]